# css code in which i want to change the color of the icon too when i focus on that paceholder

Tags: html, css, forms, sass, html5-canvas

```css
.password:focus,.email:focus{
    border-bottom: 3px solid #e84118;
    color: #e84118;
   
    .icon_password:focus,.icon_email:focus{
      color: #e84118;
    }
}
```

It is not the proper code i just want when i focus on the placeholder the icon automatically change its colour.Thanks in advance.

Comment: just remove `:focus` pseudo-class from `.icon_password` and `.icon_email` and you should be fine

Comment: and please, provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1):

keep in mind that if you want to change te field in wich you put your password, you use ' `background-color:`

`color:` only changes text

Comment: He's asking how to change icon color, not background color. Icon color could depend on `color` value (if it's an icon font like fontawesome) or on `fill` value if it's a SVG

Comment: *________ i am saying i have already given a particular color to both border_bottom and the icon. And now when i focus upon placeholder i can change its color using :focus but now i am asking how to change the icon color automatically if  focus the cursor on the placeholder lying in front of it.